# Whats the purpose of Vector capacity

Tags: java

The Vector API defines 4 different constructors:

```
Vector()

Vector(Collection<? extends E> c)

Vector(int initialCapacity)

Vector(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement)
```

but how do they work and what are they used for? Why should i want to define a fixed capacity for a vector? Even if i set the initial capacity to 100, I can add a 101. item to the vector:

```
Vector<Object> test = new Vector<Object>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    test.add(new Object());
}

test.add(new Object());
System.out.println(test.size());
System.out.println(test.capacity());
```

In the above code, the second sysout (test.capacity()) writes 200. Why is the capacity in this vector 200? The initial capacity is 100 and i didn't defined a capacity increment.

I really wonder if theres any real world example where these constrcutors are used?

And a smiliar question:
whats exactly the difference between Vector.get(int position) and Vector.elementAt(int position)? I read that the method get was defined before Vector was added to the Collection class and so it was necessary to add the method elementAt(int position) later too. Is that true? Or are there any other differences?

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to use `Vector`, you probably should use `ArrayList` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300519/arraylist-vs-vectors-in-java-if-thread-safety-isnt-a-concern

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### What's an "initial" capacity?

The *initial* capacity is simply that: the capacity of the `Vector` at construction time.

A `Vector` is a dynamically growable data structure, and it would reallocate its backing array as necessary. Thus, there is no *final* capacity, but you can set what its *initial* value is.

Here's an excerpt from [`Vector` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> Each vector tries to optimize storage management by maintaining a `capacity` and a `capacityIncrement`. The `capacity` is always at least as large as the vector `size`; it is usually larger because as components are added to the vector, the vector's storage increases in chunks the size of `capacityIncrement`. An application can increase the `capacity` of a vector before inserting a large number of components; this reduces the amount of incremental reallocation.

Note that post-construction, you can also use [`ensureCapacity`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) to achieve the same effect.

#### See also

- [When you create a collection object (List, Set, etc), usually they take a parameter known as “initialCapacity”. What does this parameter mean and how is it used ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035151/when-you-create-a-collection-object-list-set-etc-usually-they-take-a-paramet)

---

### Why does it matter?

Let's say for example you have 100 elements that you want to insert into a `Vector`. The [nullary constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28%29) sets a `Vector` to have an initial capacity of 10, and doubles in size when growing. This means that to accommodate 100 elements, it would double to 20, 40, 80, and then finally 160, before it can fit all 100 elements.

Note that 4 incremental reallocation steps were performed, and when it finally fits all 100 elements, only 60% of the actual capacity is used. On the other hand, an [`ensureCapacity(100)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) (or using the appropriate constructor overload to achieve the same effect) prior to insertion would make the process more efficient, since there's no excess unused capacity, and the array would only need to be reallocated once.

Do note that *asymptotically, the two processes above are equally optimal* (`O(N)` time and `O(N)` space), but of course the the latter is a constant-time improvement over the former both in space and time.

Of course, if you set `ensureCapacity(10000000)`, and only insert 100 elements, you'd be using only .001% of the capacity -- what a waste! So if you know ahead of time how many elements you're about to insert, you can make the process more efficient (by a constant factor) by using `ensureCapacity`, but in any case `Vector` still does a fine job on its own even without your help.

#### See also

- [Java Set Initial Capacity Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564899/java-set-initial-capacity-best-practice)

---

### Why doubling?

Without going into details, this doubling in growth is a form of geometric expansion, which is what enabled constant-time amortized analysis per operation for `Vector`. It's worth noting that [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), a similar growable data structure backed by an array, doesn't even specify the details of its growth policy, but the [OpenJDK version](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java&l=183) has a growth factor of `3/2`.

Do note that `Vector` actually allows you to set a non-geometric growth factor with [`capacityIncrement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#capacityIncrement). **It's important to realize that if you set** `capacityIncrement` **to a small non-zero value, you can in fact make** `Vector` **perform horrible asymptotically**. If you set it to `1`, for example, then adding `N` elements would be an `O(N^2)` operation!

`ArrayList` doesn't let you customize its growth policy, since you're not even supposed to know (nor care, really!).

#### See also

- [Wikipedia: Dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

  - See: *Geometric expansion and amortized cost*

---

### Miscellaneous

> What about `elementAt` and `get`?

Straight from [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt%28int%29):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, making it a member of the [Java Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Unlike the new collection implementations, `Vector` is `synchronized`.
>
> `public E elementAt(int index)` : Returns the component at the specified index. This method is identical in functionality to the `get(int)` method (which is part of the `List` interface).

So chronologically, `Vector` had `elementAt`, before it was retrofitted to implement `List`, and therefore must implement `get`.

Note the part about `Vector` being `synchronized`. If you don't need this feature, `ArrayList` would be a much better choice since you're not paying for the cost of thread-safety.

#### See also

- [ArrayList vs. Vectors in Java if thread safety isn’t a concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300519/arraylist-vs-vectors-in-java-if-thread-safety-isnt-a-concern)

Answer (score 4):

If you specify a zero or negative capacity increment, the capacity of the vector is doubled every time, as per the documentation for the `capacityIncrement` field:

> The amount by which the capacity of
>   the vector is automatically
>   incremented when its size becomes
>   greater than its capacity. If the
>   capacity increment is less than or
>   equal to zero, the capacity of the
>   vector is doubled each time it needs
>   to grow.

If you only specify the capacity, the default `capacityIncrement` is zero - hence the doubling behaviour.

You would specify a capacity if you already had a good idea of how large your collection would need to be - this avoids unnecessary copying.

As for `get` and `elementAt()` - yes, `elementAt()` was added for the general collections API. Looking at the implementation, they're identical other than the precise details of the exception thrown in the error case.

Comment: Thanks - but if i allocate the memory at initialisation then i have the advantage that i don't need to allocate memory when i increment the vector (i think that's done because of time saving?) but on the other hand, i could be that i allocated memory on the instantiation of the vector which i don't need right now and therefore i waste memory?

Comment: @Sebi: It's not just allocating the memory as you add extra elements - it's copying the existing data into the new array. But yes, if you over-allocate, you're wasting memory - which is why you only specify a capacity if you have a reasonable idea of how many elements you're going to want to add.