# v<int>pos(MAX) v<int> tmp Which is of non-class type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’ pos[i].push_back(tmp);

Tags: c++, vector, terminal, compiler-errors, stl

C++ (STL):

```
Request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘pos.std::vector<int>::operator[](((std::vector<int>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’
   pos[i].push_back(tmp);
vector<int> pos(MAX), vector<int> tmp;
```

I can't figure out why my code is getting wrong.
So, Please tell, why is this error coming

Goal: I can't give the whole code as i faced the problem now only while coding a solution to a part of a code in a running contest. So, Please 
just tell me about this error. Then, my all other parts of code will work fine.

MY CODE:

```
/*
 Name: SUSHANT OBEROI
 College: MNNIT ALLAHABAD
 Email: sushantoberoi3@gmail.com
 Handle: soc3
*/

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define sd(a) scanf("%d", &a)
#define slld(a) scanf("%lld", &a)
#define fl(i, a, b) for(int i=a; i<b; i++)
#define fle(i, a, b) for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
#define ll long long
#define wl(q) while(q--)
#define MAX 300005
#define mp make_pair
#define fi first
#define se second
#define mod 1000000007

void print_output() {                                                                               
    vector<int> pos(MAX);
    fl(i, 0, 100) {
        pos[i].clear();
        vector<int> tmp;
        fl(j, 0, 100) 
            tmp.push_back(j);
        pos[i].push_back(tmp);
    }
}

int main() {
    print_output();
    return 0;
}
```

I think (according to me only, i don't what's the correct answer is?)
that i am doing it correctly but compiler is wrong. (Sorry for saying this, but i think).

Comment: pos[i].push_back(tmp) - what do you expect this to do? Note that `pos` is a `vector` of `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `vector<int> pos(MAX);` which is a vector of `int`. The expression `pos[i]` returns a reference to an element of the vector, which in this case is an `int`. The statement `pos[i].push_back(tmp);` tries to call a `push_back()` member function on an `int`, which is not a class and does not have that member function.

Perhaps you meant to create a `vector<vector<int>> pos(MAX);`, a vector of vectors. I don't know and after seeing `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and those `#define` lines I'm not interested in the rest of the code.

Comment: Then also the same error is coming. Please check yourself as well on linux terminal.

Comment: @sushantoberoi If you want to assign `tmp` to `pos[i]` you can just do `pos[i] = tmp;`. It looks like you don't want `pos` to grow (using `push_back`) since you've created it with a given size so just try assignment. Again, I'm just guessing what you're attempting.

Comment: Thanks Sir, it's not like that i don't want to grow pos, we can do that, and now i can successfully submit the solution for the contest. But, i usually used pos[i].push_back(tmp), so i coded it up like that. Please, just tell one more thing, how to remove this error if i want to use push_back() without limting the size.

Comment: @sushantoberoi You could define `vector<vector<int>> pos;`, note this creates an empty vector, and then do `pos.push_back(tmp);` to append `tmp` to the end of `pos`. See it [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/2g8NPX).

Comment: If i define it like that, Please tell why is it wrong?

Comment: I am saying, I have not written any code which violated C++ syntax. I want to ask, then, why compiler is giving error?

Comment: @sushantoberoi Because `vector<int>` is a vector of `int` (a one-dimensional dynamic array of `int`). This means `pos[i]` is an `int`, not a vector of `int`. Attempting to call `push_back()` on an `int` is a syntax error. That's like trying to do `int meow; meow.push_back(42);` which is not valid code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296945/size-vs-capacity-of-a-vector Sir, just refer to this article once to differentiate between (MAX) and [MAX] and please tell me also if I am wrong?

Comment: @sushantoberoi `vector<int> pos(MAX);` (with parentheses) defines a vector with a **size()** of MAX elements. Just like if you had used `pos.resize(MAX)` to set the size. `vector<int> pos[MAX];` (with square brackets) defines an **array** of vectors. This is an array of size MAX, each element is an empty vector.

Comment: Sir initially you suggested vector<vector<int>> pos so i thought now also you saying like this vector<vector<int>> pos  that's why I couldn't figure out this thing at that time. But now I understood that you are suggesting vector<int> pos[MAX]. Thanks for the answer and investing your precious time.